# How to Download This Node.js Result to Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, download

Here is my code:

```
function exportFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  app.set('drive', drive);
  var fileId = '1qupvie1LqNdLj-1TZNu3x6-4bT411C4F2YYGSfpc7yk';
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./src/test.txt');

  drive.files.export({
    fileId: fileId, mimeType: 'text/plain'}, 
    {responseType: 'stream'},
    function(err, response){
    if(err)return console.log(err);
    response.data.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err);
    }).on('end', ()=>{
        console.log("sent file.")
    })
    .pipe(dest);
});
}
```

This is part of a greater app that allows users to download the result of this function, into their download folder. This is able to write to the specified destination just fine, but how would I call this on this up on the front-end on React? What would be the best way to go about making a download button on the front end to return this result?

Answer (score 0):

You serve the file with any webserver,  and as you are using node.js, express is a good choice.  You put the downloaded content into the public directory.
http://expressjs.com/

on the client with or without framework, you can show the user a download link, with a download link. the  tag should contain the attribute `download` as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score -1):

1. Run node with the --inspect flag: **node --inspect fileName.js**
2. It’ll redirect you to **chrome://inspect**
3. Click the Open dedicated DevTools for Node link (**inspect**).